# pysimplegui: why does a working layout fail in a Column / Frame?

Tags: python, pysimplegui, col

A working layout looses part of the information when used in a 'Column' or 'Frame'.
Minimized source:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lo = [
        [sg.T("Line 1")],
        [sg.T("Aa"),sg.T("Bb")],
        [
            [sg.T("1  "),sg.T("2")], # (*)
            [sg.T("3  "),sg.T("4")], # (*)
            [sg.T("5  "),sg.T("6")], # (*)
        ]
    ]
# (1)
layout=lo
# (2) layout=[[sg.Column(lo),sg.T("TEST")]]
# (3) layout=[[sg.Frame("Test",lo),sg.T("TEST")]]

window = sg.Window('W', layout)
while(True):
    event,values=window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED,"Cancel"):
        break
window.close
```

Using the Layout alone (1) I get the following window:

[image]

activating lines (2) or (3) instead, the (*) marked lines are marked as errors and are omitted from the window:

[image]

For demonstration a "TEST" string was added; same problem without it.
Any idea what's wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: What is the reason for putting the numbers in an extra list, so what do you want to achieve here?

Comment: The format of a layout should be in a list of lists of elements. Wrong format for the `lo` here.

Comment: As Jason said, the initial layout, lo, has an extra set of [] in it and thus not a valid list of lists.  The difference you see may be:  Window layouts was made to be more permissive in these "errors" and ignores them so that list comprehensions are easier to use. The layouts of Columns / Frames may be are more restrictive. I don't recall if the loosy-goosy rules for layouts have been added to Columns and Frames, but it appears it may not yet be as permissive.  I would have thought you would see an error popup when trying `lo` with a Column

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but not putting the numbers in a list may already solve your issue:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

lo = [
        [sg.T("Line 1")],
        [sg.T("Aa"),sg.T("Bb")],
        [sg.T("1  "),sg.T("2")], # (*)
        [sg.T("3  "),sg.T("4")], # (*)
        [sg.T("5  "),sg.T("6")], # (*)
    ]
# (1)
layout=lo
layout=[[sg.Column(lo),sg.T("TEST")]]
# (3) layout=[[sg.Frame("Test",lo),sg.T("TEST")]]

window = sg.Window('W', layout)
while(True):
    event,values=window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED,"Cancel"):
        break
window.close
```

Will give you:
[image]

Comment: Well, I should be more precise:  there are 30 Sets of data, all aligned as shown in the column. The headline "Line1", the column headers "Aa  Bb" and the data lines 1 2 / 3 4 / 5 6 are generated from different functions (are a bit more complex with many options for each field) and put together in a way like 'lo' looks like. I will try to change the program following your solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your initial layout is not "legal" in the strict definition of a layout being a "list of lists".

If I attempt to run the code provided:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# This layout has an error....
lo = [
        [sg.T("Line 1")],
        [sg.T("Aa"),sg.T("Bb")],
        [           # <--- THIS bracket is not "legal" in a Column layout
            [sg.T("1  "),sg.T("2")], # (*)
            [sg.T("3  "),sg.T("4")], # (*)
            [sg.T("5  "),sg.T("6")], # (*)
        ]
    ]
# (1)
# layout=lo
layout=[[sg.Column(lo),sg.T("TEST")]]
# (3) layout=[[sg.Frame("Test",lo),sg.T("TEST")]]

window = sg.Window('W', layout)
while(True):
    event,values=window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED,"Cancel"):
        break
window.close()
```

then I see an error popup that describes the error precisely:

[image]

Not sure why you're not seeing this error message.

Comment: saw this message and clicked it away, not really understanding what I can do to fix it. Your comment made clear what I was misunderstanding. Thanks a lot!